# how to generate a slideshow in swf format from python?

Tags: python, django, pyamf, ming

how to generate a sildeshow in swf format from python/django?

basically i have a list of images and text and I would like to use python to generate a swf file.

I checked seems using MING or PyAMF is the direction to go but I dont quite understand how it should work.

thanks.

Comment: does it have to be a swf? And do the images have to be embedded in the swf? There are lots of javascript based plugins that could do the same thing. Just pass them a list of images from django.

Comment: have to be swf
any idea? thanks.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.maani.us/xml_slideshow/ and generate the xml in django?

Comment: thanks it seems direction to go
it looks like
1. configure my django app to generate a xml with the static data
2. use xml_slideshow to generate the swf

anyhow or document for me to learn more to program the swf file? i tried to google but i dont find something obvious. i would like to have more control on my slideshow. thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, the advantage of using a plugin is that you don't have to program swf. That bit is already done for you, just supply the xml

Comment: Something like this is a javascript alternative: http://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-carousel/

Comment: thanks :) but i need swf
any document to "program" swf? i am totally new on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to create an swf slideshow you need to use Adobe Flash, a suitable tutorial: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/slideshow/.

To output the xml file from django, use a view that outputs xml:

**views.py**

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse

def slideshow_xml(request, pk):
    slideshow = Slideshow.objects.get(pk=pk)
    xml = render_to_string('xml_template.xml', {'slideshow': slideshow})

    return HttpResponse(xml, mimetype="application/xml")
```

This would respond to a url like `/slideshow/10/` and retrieves the `SlideShow` object with id 10, this is then passed to an xml template to be rendered:

**Template xml_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slideshow width="{{ slideshow.width }}" height="{{ slideshow.height }}" speed="{{ slideshow.speed }}">
     {% for image in slideshow.slideshowimage_set.all %}
      <image url="{{ image.image.url }}" title="{{ image.title }}" />
     {% endfor %}
</slideshow>
```

This will output the xml format as required for the tutorial above. It extracts the data stored in the objects to create the xml file.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class SlideShow(Models.model):
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    speed = models.IntegerField()

class SlideShowImage(Models.model):
    slideshow = models.ForeignKey(SlideShow)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='slideshow_images/')
```

These models can be created in the admin interface of django and allow the parameters of the slideshow to be specified. An arbitrary number of `SlideShowImage` objects can be created and connected to a single `SlideShow` object.

If you haven't used django before the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) will get you far enough to understand the above.

Is this something like what you want?

Comment: thanks! exactly! i will check more and work on my stuff and let you know more later, may be weekend. thanks a lot for your help.